# How to protect PHP from the public?

Tags: php, security, permissions

So I'm a bit confused about what crafty users can and can't see on a site.

If I have a file with a bunch of php script, the user cant see it just by clicking "view source."  But is there a way they can "download" the entire page including the php?

If permission settings should pages be set to, if there is php script that must execute on load but that I dont want anyone to see?

Thanks

Comment: PHP is excecuted on the server side, so only processed code will be sent to the web client. The only way to see PHP code is if your webserver isn't configured properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 steps.

**Step 1**: So long as your PHP is being processed properly this is nothing to worry about...do that.

**Step 2**: As an insurance measure move the majority of your PHP code outside of the Web server directory and then just include it from the PHP files that are in the directory.  PHP will include on the file system and therefore have access to the files, but the Web server will not.  On the off chance that the Web server gets messed up and serves your raw PHP code (happened to Facebook at one point), the user won't see anything but a reference to a file they can't access.

Answer (score 0):

PHP files are processed by the server before being sent to your web browser. That is, the actual PHP code, comments, etc. cannot be seen by the client. For someone to access your php files, they have to hack into your server through FTP or SSH or something similar, and you have bigger problems than just your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on your web server and its configuration.  It's the web server's job to take a url and decide whether to run a script or send back a file.  Commonly, the suffix of a filename, file's directory, or the file's permission attributes in the filesystem are used to make this decision.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side scripting language that is executed on server. There is no way it can be accessed client side.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is enabled, and if the programs are well tagged, none of the PHP code will go past your web server. To make things further secure, disable directory browsing, and put an empty index.php or index.html in all the folders.

Ensure that you adhere to secure coding practices too. There are quite a number of articles in the web. Here is one http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-secure-apps/index.html